# Stack small icon over a large icon with font-awesome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a round '+' button using font-awesome. I'm attaching an image of a similar button from google contacts:

[image]

I tried to use font-awesome's icon stack as follows:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

But this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the plus sign is very large and bold. I would like to have the plus icon much smaller than the circle around it and much thiner.

I tried moving the `fa-5x` to the circle icon (removing it from the span item), but this make the whole icon become small. I tried playing only with the plus sign size by giving it `fa-1x` but this leaves it as-is (if I put `fa-5x` it makes it much larger than the circle).

Is there away to achieve what I'm trying to do?

[Here's a JSFiddle with my experiments](https://jsfiddle.net/aviet/j6ky10Lc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother using FontAwesome for this. You can do it with a single element and some CSS, and it gives you way more control over the sizing of each individual element.

This technique uses CSS Psuedo Elements which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/). They allow you to create shapes and style content that doesn't exist in the markup necessarily.

Here's what I came up with:

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/j6ky10Lc/1/)

```css
body
{
    padding: 50px; /* For this demo only */
}

.circle
{
    display: block;
    background: #3498db;
    width: 120px;  /* Can be any size you want */
    height: 120px; /* Can be any size you want */
    border-radius: 50%; /* Makes the div a circle */
    position: relative; /* Allows you to position the pseudo elements */
}

.circle:before, .circle:after
{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #fff;
}

.circle:before
{
    width: 4px;
    height: 32px;
    top: calc(50% - 16px); /* 16px = half of the height */
    left: calc(50% - 2px); /* 2px = half of the width */
}

.circle:after
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 4px;
    top: calc(50% - 2px);   /* 2px = half of the height */
    left: calc(50% - 16px); /* 16px = half of the width */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really great. I'm not a CSS expert so I wonder, where is the '+' sign coming from? I couldn't quite figure that out.

Comment: You should have a look around at CSS Pseudo Elements. The plus sign is made out of two shapes. The horizontal line and the vertical line. The horizontal line is created by the `:before` pseudo element and the vertical line is created by the `:after` pseudo element. I will update the answer to include a better description of this.